# Creating right-click menu on splitter handle in PyQt5 python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have made a splitter. I have been trying to bring a right-click menu when the splitter handle is right-clicked.

Here is the code I have created. Currently, it doesn't recognise the right clicks on the handle of the splitter. (note: this code currently updates count if right-clicked in the first frame of the splitter i,e Top left frame)

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


# This class is to create the outer window

class OuterLayout(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window()

    def window(self):
        self.setMinimumSize(1000, 900)
        self.showMaximized()
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Images/Logo_small.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle('Splitter')
        self.menu_bar()

        inner_layout = SplitterLayout()
        layout = inner_layout.add_layout()

        self.setCentralWidget(layout)


    def menu_bar(self):
        menu_bar = self.menuBar()

        file_menu = menu_bar.addMenu('File')
        self.file(file_menu)

        edit_menu = menu_bar.addMenu('Edit')
        self.edit(edit_menu)

    def file(self, file):

        new = QAction('New', self)

        file.addAction(new)

    def edit(self, edit):
        pass


# This class creates the splitter window
class SplitterLayout(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__()
        self.count = 0
        self.splitter_handle_width = 3 # This is to set the width of the handle

    # This is a method to add a new splitter window
    def add_layout(self):

        left = QFrame()
        left.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        bottom = QFrame()
        bottom.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        splitter1 = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter1.setHandleWidth(self.splitter_handle_width)

        lineedit = QLineEdit()
        lineedit.setStyleSheet('background-color:green')

        splitter1.addWidget(left)
        splitter1.addWidget(lineedit)
        splitter1.setSizes([200, 200])
        print(splitter1.handle(3))

        splitter1.mousePressEvent = self.splitter_clicked

        splitter2 = QSplitter(Qt.Vertical)
        splitter2.setHandleWidth(self.splitter_handle_width)

        splitter2.addWidget(splitter1)
        splitter2.addWidget(bottom)

        return splitter2

    def splitter_clicked(self, event):
        self.count += 1
        print('splitter_double clicked' + str(self.count))

    # def mousePressEvent(self, event):
    #     if event.button == Qt.RightButton:
    #         print('Right mouse clicked')
    #
    #     elif event.button == Qt.LeftButton:
    #         print('Left mouse clicked')


def main():
    splitter = QApplication([])

    outer_layout = OuterLayout()
    outer_layout.show()

    splitter.exec_()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to create a custom `QSplitterHandle` class and override `QSplitterHandle.mousePressEvent` and a custom `QSplitter` class where you override `createHandle` so that it returns the custom `QSplitterHandle` instead of the standard one, i.e.

```
class MySplitter(QSplitter):
    def createHandle(self):
        return MySplitterHandle(self.orientation(), self)


class MySplitterHandle(QSplitterHandle):
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            print('Right mouse clicked')

        elif event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            print('Left mouse clicked')

        super().mousePressEvent(event)
```

Finally, to use the custom `QSplitter` you need to replace all occurrences of `QSplitter` with `MySplitter` in `SplitterLayout`.